# Where does the word "to" refer to in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

This is a paragraph from a **programming language book**:

> It's important to know that C# cannot exist alone; after all, it's a
> language that runs on variants  of .NET. In theory, someone could
> write a compiler for C# that uses a different platform, with
> different underlying types. In practice, the platform for C# is .NET,
> which provides tens of  thousands of types to C#, including
> System.Int32, **which is the C# keyword alias int maps  to**, as well as
> many more complex types, such as System.Xml.Linq.XDocument

I want to know what is the role of "to" in **which is the C# keyword alias int maps to** grammatically and also what does the word "to" refer to?

Comment: It refers to `System.Int32` – meaning `int` maps to `System.Int32`. If it referred to the earlier `.NET` then there would be an 'and': "**and** which is the C# keyword alias int maps to" but that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It's bad grammar. It should read, "..., which is ***what*** the C# keyword alias "int" maps to", or "..., ***which*** the C# keyword alias "int" maps to" (no "which is").

Answer (score 1):

It could be rephrased, slightly more formally, to

> In practice, the platform for C# is .NET, which provides tens of
> thousands of types to C#, including System.Int32, to which the C#
> keyword alias int maps [...]

That might make it clearer that int maps to System.Int32.